# What is the first Bollywood film to have a sequel/prequel?

Tags: first-appearance, sequels, prequels, indian-cinema

What is the first Bollywood film to have a sequel or prequel ?

The oldest I found is [Nigahen: Nagina Part II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigahen:_Nagina_Part_II) from 1989. But I think there should be more that are older than this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hunter Wali* film series was the movie series to have a sequel. First movie was released in 1935 and its sequel in 1943.

The first movie *[Hunterwali(1935)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunterwali)* was the first movie to have a sequel. This was an action movie with [Fearless Nadia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fearless_Nadia) as lead role. This movie is one of the earliest female-lead movies.

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunterwali) page of the movie:

> A story of a princess who fights injustice as the masked crusader Hunterwali (lit. "lady with the whip"), the film propelled Nadia and the Wadia brothers of Wadia Movietone to fame.

Because of this movie's success, Nadia became a popular actress and a popular stunt woman. She starred in numerous action movies.

**Reception:**

> Hunterwali was a runaway success and a bonanza in terms of money earned, as it ran for 25 weeks making record earnings for the year.This was Nadia's and Wadia Movietone's first big success.

As a sequel of this movie, another movie was released. It is [*Hunterwali Ki Beti(1943)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunterwali_Ki_Beti). This movie was also a blockbuster just like the first movie.

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunterwali_Ki_Beti) of the movie:

> Hunterwali Ki Beti is a Bollywood film. It was released in 1943, and is the sequel to the 1935 film Hunterwali.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunterwali_Ki_Beti) Both films starred Fearless Nadia as the heroine and were produced by the Wadia brothers JBH and Homi (her husband) of Wadia Movietone.

This movie series made the suffix *wali* famous in Indian films and many movies were released with this suffix like [*Cyclewali(1938)*](http://www.gomolo.com/cyclewali-movie/678), [*Motorwali(1942)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorwali)

Answer (score 6):

After searching for a long time i concluded that [Nigahen: Nagina Part II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigahen%3a_Nagina_Part_II) is the first Bollywood sequel follow-up of [Nagina (1986)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagina_%28film%29).  (Sources:[1](http://www.bollywood.com/node/22722),[2](http://in.movies.yahoo.com/blogs/24fps/first-among-sequels-085811712.html))

Answer (score 6):

[Suraksha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surakshaa) from 1979 stars [Mithun Chakraborty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithun_Chakraborty) (as Gunmaster G9, a Hindi James Bond-type) that was followed by the sequel [Wardat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardat_%281981_film%29) in 1981.

[Videsh](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1565053/) 1977 part 1 and [Agent Vinod](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165610/) 1977 part 2 both contain [Mahendra Sandhu](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0761888/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) as Agent Vinod.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. There isn't much context here to go with. Can you expound on your answer to provide more insight?

Comment: Hopefully my edit will keep this answer alive. Pretty much a complete rehaul, but the information seems legit.

Answer (score -1):

Jewel Thief 1967 AND 1996,  Return of Jewel Thief

Comment: 1996 doesn't look earlier then existing answers.